# Most thorough way to determine the user-perspective "type" of a file in Linux?

Tags: mime-types, file-types

I am looking (in a file-manager sort of application) to provide the most pertinent natural-language description of what kind of a file each file in a directory is. There seem to be several command-line mechanisms that do portions of this, with overlapping strengths. Let's look at their behavior on a couple of relatively non-exotic test cases. (The -b options are just so that the filenames were not redundantly printed in these examples.)

1. A public key generated for me by ssh-keygen (it chose the filename):

```
~> file -b xgl_ed25519.pub
OpenSSH ED25519 public key
~> mimetype -d -b xgl_ed25519.pub
Microsoft Publisher document
~> mimetype -d -M -b xgl_ed25519.pub # -M = "ignore extension"
plain text document
```

file is spot on, mimetype is terribly confused, and mimetype -M is true but unhelpfully unspecific.

2. A hand-written Markdown file:

```
Notes> file -b servers.md
Nim source code, Unicode text, UTF-8 text, with very long lines (5244)
Notes> mimetype -d -b servers.md
Markdown document
Notes> mimetype -d -M -b servers.md
plain text document
```

file is bizarrely confused, mimetype is spot on, and again mimetype -M is correct but less helpful.

3. A JPEG file that happened to come my way with a nonstandard extension:

```
GVIP> file -b example.img
JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 960x720, components 3
GVIP> GVIP> mimetype -d -b example.img
Raw disk image
GVIP> mimetype -d -M -b example.img
JPEG image
```

Here file is correct but super-loquacious, mimetype is confused, and mimetype -M is spot on.

The point of these examples is that I relatively routinely encounter different examples where each one of these methods produces the best/most practical answer that I would like to present to the user. But determining a good user-perspective characterization of files must be a problem that has received significant attention; after all, most every file manager out there has a "type" field. (I recognize there are also mime typers, like `file -i`, `mimetype` with no flags, and `xdg-mime query filetype`, but mime types are rather verbose and not very user-friendly; I am looking for a natural-language description, and plus there is still the issue of knowing whether or not to trust the extension.)

So the question is, what's the most reliable way to get a useful/accurate/specific characterization of the sort of thing a file is? I'd rather not cobble together some sort of logic like "try `file` and if it produces something short and specific, go with that, but if not, compare `mimetype` with and without the `-M` flag and decide which to trust based on the results: if the answer without -M is compatible with but more specific than with -M, use that, otherwise use the -M answer". (And frankly, I'd rather not use "mimetype" at all, since it introduces a dependency on the more-or-less obsolete Perl language. Isn't there a more modern way to access the descriptions in the mime type database?)

Anyhow, for the general file characterization problem, I am not limited to a command-line solution; if there is a relatively common, current language with a library that would be good for this, I could potentially also use that. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I don't think there is a *reliable* way to determine a file type. `mimetype` without `-M` seems to rely on the file name "extension", i.e. the file name part after the last dot, while `file` checks magic numbers/patterns in the file. Both can fail as your examples demonstrate.

Comment: I guess I am imagining some very slightly smart algorithm that looks at the file to get a confidence level that it can tell what the contents are, and if that confidence level is high, go with that, otherwise go with the description based on the mime type from the extension. After all, a person has no trouble figuring out which of the tools is right in a given case.

Answer (score 0):

I would never accept this answer, I just thought I should share the ad-hoc abomination I am currently using. It's slow and oh-so-crufty, but seems to produce pretty helpful results. I like that for zero-length files it produces 'empty' as the file type; I haven't seen any file manager that does that.

As it's a quick prototype, it's in the form of a xonsh script. If you're not familiar with xonsh, in this case you can just assume it's python with a very convenient syntax `$(blah bloo)` for capturing the output of command `blah bloo`.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env xonsh
import re

filesez = $(file -b $ARG1)
filesez = filesez.strip()

# file is very good at detecting scripts:
script = re.search(r'\w*\s*script', filesez)
if script:
   print(script.group())
   exit(0)

# If file said anything complicated, we'll try mimetype
punctuation = re.search(r'[,;]', filesez)
# For text files, assume the extension is right
trust = (filesez == 'ASCII text')
if not (punctuation or trust):
   print(filesez)
   exit(0)

# OK, didn't get enough info from file, try mimetype
# Use a format that gives both the mime type and
# the description at once, to save calls
oformat = r'--output-format=%m|%d'
mimewith = $(mimetype @(oformat) $ARG1)
[mimetypewith, descwith] = mimewith.strip().split('|')

# Usually we go with the extension
desc = descwith
# And we always do with text files, as mentioned above
trust = (trust or 'Unicode text' in filesez)
if not trust:
   mimewithout = $(mimetype -M @(oformat) $ARG1)
   [mimetypewithout, descwithout] = mimewithout.strip().split('|')
   if mimetypewith.split('/')[0] == mimetypewithout.split('/')[0]:
      # If the types are compatible, believe the extension
      desc = descwith
   else:
      desc = descwithout

# Calling everything a document is a waste of screenspace:
if desc.endswith(' document'):
   desc = desc[0:-9]

# All right, we've done the best we can:
print(desc)
```

Please post a better answer if you have one; I'd really like to clean this up.